How use js object in css method
I'm trying to use js objects like CSSType, in css method to apply style into compontent, converting object to string, but the method don't accept use something like css${style}. Someone know a way to use use a string or object into css method?
import { Properties } from 'csstype';
import {LitElement, css, html} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';
import { convertStyle } from '../utils/convert-style';

const style: Properties = {
  color: 'blue'
}

@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`${convertStyle(style)}`;

  render() {
    return html`<p>Hello, World!</p>`;
  }
}


import { Properties } from "csstype";

/***
 * this function convert a Properties object into string
*/
export function convertStyle(style: Properties) {
  return Object.entries(style)
  .map(([key, value]) => `${key.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase()}: ${value};`)
  .join(' ');
}


To provide a string into an expression to static styles, you need to use unsafeCSS.
import {unsafeCSS} from 'lit';

@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`
    p {
      ${unsafeCSS(convertStyle(style))}      
    }
  `;

  render() {
    return html`<p>Hello, World!</p>`;
  }
}

Alternatively, to use the object as is, you can use styleMap.
import {styleMap} from 'lit/directives/style-map.js';


@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`<p style=${styleMap(style)}>Hello, World!</p>`;
  }
}

